# Send selected options from react dual listbox with post request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement in my react app, two react double listbox in my component. At the moment the listboxes are filled automatically after a get request when component mounts. I need some help on how to get the selected options in each double listbox and send them to the server as json data.
I need two arrays from these lists.

This is my dual listbox classes:

```
import React from 'react';
import DualListBox from 'react-dual-listbox';
import 'react-dual-listbox/lib/react-dual-listbox.css';
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';

export class FirstList extends React.Component {
    state = {
        selected: [],
    };

    onChange = (selected) => {
        this.setState({ selected });
    };

    render() {
        const { selected } = this.state;

        return (
            <DualListBox
                canFilter
                filterPlaceholder={this.props.placeholder || 'Search From List 1...'}
                options={this.props.options}
                selected={selected}
                onChange={this.onChange}
            />
        );
    }
}

export class SecondList extends React.Component {
    state = {
        selected: [],
    };

    onChange = (selected) => {
        this.setState({ selected });
    };

    render() {
        const { selected } = this.state;

        return (
            <DualListBox
                canFilter
                filterPlaceholder={this.props.placeholder || 'Search From List 2...'}
                options={this.props.options}
                selected={selected}
                onChange={this.onChange}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

In my component I started importing this:

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
        import LoadingSpinner from '../shared/ui-elements/LoadingSpinner';
        import ErrorModal from '../shared/ui-elements/ErrorModal';
        import { FirstList, SecondList } from '../shared/formElements/DualListBox';
        import { useHttpClient } from '../shared/hooks/http-hook';
        
        const MyComponent = () => {
        const { isLoading, error, sendRequest, clearError } = useHttpClient();
        const [loadedRecords, setLoadedRecords] = useState();
        
         useEffect(() => {
                const fetchRecords = async () => {
                    try {
                        const responseData = await sendRequest(
                            process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL + '/components/get'
                        );
                        setLoadedRecords(responseData)
                    } catch (err) { }
                };
                fetchRecords();
            }, [sendRequest]);
        
        ...
        
        ...
        
         return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <ErrorModal error={error} onClear={clearError} />
        <form>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <fieldset name="SerialField" className="border p-4">
                            <legend className="scheduler-border"></legend>
                            <div className="container">
                                <p>SERIALS</p>
                                {loadedRecords ? (
                                    <FirstList id='Serials' options={loadedRecords.firstRecordsList} />
                                ) : (
                                        <div>
                                            <label>List is loading, please wait...</label>
                                            {isLoading && <LoadingSpinner />}
                                        </div>
                                    )}
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <fieldset name="SystemsField" className="border p-4">
                            <legend className="scheduler-border"></legend>
                            <div className="container">
                                <p>SYSTEMS</p>
                                {loadedRecords ? (
                                    <SecondList options={loadedRecords.secondRecordsList} />
                                ) : (
                                        <div>
                                            <label>List is loading, please wait...</label>
                                            {isLoading && <LoadingSpinner />}
                                        </div>
                                    )}
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>

...

...
```

If anyone could guide me it'll be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FirstList` and `SecondList` are using internal state to show the selected values. Since a parent component should do the server request, it needs access to this data. This can be achieved by a variety of options:

1. **Let the parent component (`MyComponent`) handle the state completely.** `FirstList` and `SecondList` would need two props: One for the currently `selected` values and another for the `onChange` event. `MyComponent` needs to manage that state. For example:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [firstListSelected, setFirstListSelected] = useState();
  const [secondListSelected, setSecondListSelected] = useState();
  ...
  return (
    ...
    <FirstList options={...} selected={firstListSelected} onChange={setFirstListSelected} />
    ...
    <SecondList options={...} selected={secondListSelected} onChange={setSecondListSelected} />
    ...
  )
```

2. **Provide only the `onChange` event and keep track of it.** This would be very similar to the first approach, but the lists would keep managing their state internally and only notify the parent when a change happens through `onChange`. I usually don't use that approach since it feels like I'm managing the state of something twice and I also need to know the initial state of the two `*List` components to make sure I am always synchronized properly.
3. **Use a ref, call an imperative handle when needed from the parent.** I wouldn't recommend this as it's usually not done like this and it's getting harder to share the state somewhere else than inside of the then heavily coupled components.
4. **Use an external, shared state like Redux or Unstated.** With global state, the current state can be reused anywhere in the Application and it might even exist when the user clicks away / unmounts `MyComponent`. Additional server requests wouldn't be necessary if the user navigated away and came back to the component. Anyways, using an external global state needs additional setup and usually feels "too much" and like a very high-end solution that is probably not necessary in this specific case.

By using option 1 or 2 there is a notification for the parent component when something changed. On every change a server request could be sent (might even be debounced). Or there could be a `Submit` button which has a callback that sends the saved state to the server.

Comment: I hope I haven't misunderstood the question as the question got downvoted while I was typing this answer... I understood it as search for the general approach on how to do some kind of effect when the state that is necessary is handled by child components

Comment: Thank you so much @Narigo. I implemented the first option you mentioned. It works fine. Best regards

Comment: I noticed that there's an `available` prop in the duallistbox that is a  subset of the options array to optionally filter the available list box. I tried to get them also but it returns me undefined value. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you try to achieve there and how your code would look like right now then. Does [the documentation](https://github.com/jakezatecky/react-dual-listbox#restrict-available-options) help?

Comment: I was thinking if there was a way to get the list of the options on the left side updated when the right list is filled. I needed to send to the server the information if all the options available are also selected or not, not just the values. Maybe I found a way but it's a bit twisted way... I'm just playing with useState hook, but hoped if there was a easy way. Does't seem to be reading the documentation